# Remove files in "in-pack"

Tags: git

I have a git repo, and I've done some changes (add svn, ...).

The size before work with svn was less than 1 MB, now it is 38 MB.

How to remove the extra size?

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 1041
packs: 1
size-pack: 37475
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

Comment: Try running `git gc --aggressive`

Comment: @Muhammad are you sure these are "extra" objects? If you added a large svn repo, you added all its objects.

Comment: I've tried it many time, Doesn't work!

Comment: The svn took about 15m to be checked-out, although it have only less than 1MB conent. I am sure.

Comment: It doesnt really make sense does it ? less then 1 MB and taking 15 min to checkout ;)

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy: `git svn` fetches every revision of the repo by default. So, if you have a repo with a long history, it will be big even if the most recent revision is small.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need all of your history, you can `git clone --depth DEPTH` to get only the **DEPTH** most recent commits. But then you lose your history...

Are you working locally, or over a network?